# Cannot increase timeout of Grails transaction (MyBatis)

Tags: hibernate, grails, mybatis

I am getting database timeout when executing a long running transaction in Grails using MyBatis: `java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.`

It is not feasible to improve the saving process, and it saves everything line by line by calling stored procedure described in `batisGateway.operation(params)` as many as a thousand times, which starts running slowly after a while, and may take as long as 45 minutes. However I get timeout after ~30 minutes, which makes me believe that there are some timeout set in Grails/MyBatis/Hibernate which I need to override.

- I tried adding timeout to `.withNewTransaction([timeout: 3600]) { ... }` - no effect.
- I tried various parameters in `DataSource.groovy` and `Bootstrap.groovy` - no effect
- I tried opening session and transaction manually like:

  ```
  StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession()
  Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction()
  transaction.setTimeout(4800)
  transaction.begin()
  ...
  ```

  but still no effect.

My database allows unlimited timeouts, so the problem is most likely not there. Is there something else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the connection has been evicted for some reason. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449198/grails-evicts-active-transaction